# Is it possible to change the Visual Studio indent scheme?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, indentation

I have a coding convention in my projects that I find makes method signatures nice and readable. Looks like this for example

```
    public static AxesPositions AxesAlignment
        ( Point p
        , Vector n
        , List<Point> toolInsertSection
        , double millingHeadRadius
        , double swivelAngle
        , IScrew part
        , double machiningTolerance
        , double meshEpsilon)
```

however whenever Visual Studio re-indents I get

```
    public static AxesPositions AxesAlignment
        (Point p
        , Vector n
        , List<Point> toolInsertSection
        , double millingHeadRadius
        , double swivelAngle
        , IScrew part
        , double machiningTolerance
        , double meshEpsilon)
```

Perhaps I'm OCD but seeing that first parameter jammed up against the `(` irks me. Is there any way in Visual Studio 2012 to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing without a plugin is:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Spacing > Insert space within argument list parentheses

but it's also add space before the ')', and space it even whe it hass only a one line.